# SSRS How to order tablices in a List Control?

Tags: sorting, matrix, ssrs-2008, listctrl

I am developing an RDL in SSRS 2008.  I took 3 subreports and converted them into one report.  So now I have one RDL file with 3 tablices.  But one dataset since I merged all 3 subreport datasets into one now.  (So I just joined each of these 3 tables into one).

But now I want to sort all 3 of these tablices by date field common to all.  I know I have selected a date field that all 3 tablices join on.  Then I wrapped all 3 tablices in a List Control and set this List Control to Sort by this date field: "actual_date".

But now when I view report output, it instead sorts all of Tablix A by actual_date, followed by all of Tablix B by actual_date, then followed by Tablix C by actual_date.

Instead, if a record in B occurs prior to a record in A, then I want that one B record to be listed before this one A record.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the tablixes into one. SSRS won't split up a tablix and interleave it with another one.

So make a tablix that can contain all three types of data. You can use expressions in the cells to change what field the cell displays. Then set the sorting at the appropriate level (details group or a parent group.)

Comment: Thanks Jamie.  I actually figured out how to do this with a List Control!  It turns out that a List Ctrl is a Tablix.  All I did was set sorting on the List Ctrl / Tablix on actual_date field.  And then I filtered and made visible only those sections of the dataset / tablix that were relevant to them.

Comment: Yes, the key bit is that the detail rows all need to be in the same tablix. Sub-tablixes are possible, but they won't do what you want in this case. (Lists and tables are both types of Tablix controls.)